# Identify IC marked "MC 4"

Tags: identification

Can anybody help me identify the IC marked "MC 4"?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [Analog Devices ADM3066EARMZ](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adm3061e-3062e-3063e-3064e-3065e-3066e-3067e-3068e.pdf) RS-485 transceiver.

[image]

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/RS-485-RS-422-ICs_Analog-Devices-ADM3066EARMZ_C658147.html))